# PowerPress Episode Entry Box Missing

Tags: wordpress

I have been using PowerPress for years. The Podcast Entry/Editing Box always appears at the bottom of the the post page I am editing. Suddenly, it is now in the right sidebar of the editor. How do I reset things so it appears under the post I am editing.

I have tried re-installing PowerPress, I have updated to the latest WordPress Version 5.6 and latest version of PowerPress plugin, 8.4.6. I tried with all plugins deactivated and tried with a different theme. Regardless, the Episode Box continues to stay at the bottom of the right sidebar under tags, categories, etc.

[Screenshot of Editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CpjiX.jpg)

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming questions. If you are having problems with end-user software, try [su] or https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

Custom fields must be visible!

Go to top right side of editing sidebar. Click the three vertical dots to the right of the gear. At the bottom of the drop down menu is a "Preferences" item. Select that. A light box menu system will appear in the center of the page. Make sure there is a check mark in the "Custom Fields" box. It's at the bottom of the pop-out light box menu.

Back out on the main post editing section at the bottom, a new "Custom Fields" section is exposed. Once that is visible, it is now possible to drag the "PowerPress Episode Box" to that location.

Shortly after posting this the problem came back.

I installed and reactivated the "Classic Editor" in WordPress, checked the post and everything was where it should be. After that, I deactivated the "Classic Editor" and deleted it. All is working fine now.